# Des-serializar un objeto desde una clase en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, serialización, deserialize

Buenas tengo una duda estoy intentando desserializar un objeto en java pero la desserializacion la estoy haciendo desde una clase externa al main y al pasarla a un sysout me aparece esto : [LSerializacion.Notas;@58651fd0, alguna solución? dejo código más abajo

ESTA SERÍA LA CLASE PARA SERIALIZAR Y DES-SERIALIZAR:

```
        // desearilizar
public static Object deserialize(String fileName) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fileIN = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIN);
    Object obj = (Object) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("El objeto ha sido deserealizado");
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
    return obj;
```

A CONTINUACIÓN DEJO EL MAIN:

```
try (/* VARIABLES */
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        Notas[] notas1dam = new Notas[6];
        double[] notasmedias = new double[6];
        int contador = 1;
        String nombre = "Dario";
        /* VARIABLES */

        System.out.println("Bienvenido al programa de tus notas. Introduce tus notas porfavor.");

        // INGRESAR LAS NOTAS DENTRO DEL ARRAY \ EL NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO LO HE DEFINIDO
        // ARRIBA PARA QUE NO ESTÉ PREGUNTANDO EL NOMBRE CADA VEZ Q METES LA NOTA
        for (int i = 0; i < notas1dam.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Introduce la nota de la " + contador + "º asignatura ");

            double notasalumno = sc.nextInt();
            notasmedias[i] = notasalumno;
            notas1dam[i] = new Notas(nombre, notasalumno);
            contador++;
        }

        // SERIALIZACION
        try {
            notasSerializacion.serialize(notas1dam, "hola.ser");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        // SERIALIZACION

        // DESERIALIZACION
        try {
            notasSerializacion.deserialize("hola.ser");
            // printdata(notas1dam);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        // DESERIALIZACION Y A CONTINUACIÓN SACAMOS LA MEDIA
        System.out.println("La nota media del alumno '" + nombre + "' es: " + medianotas(notasmedias));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas. He encontrado una solución la cual ha sido la siguiente;
En la clase de notasSerializacion he borrado los sysout y lo he dejado tal qque así;

```
    // desearilizar
public static Object deserialize(String fileName) throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fileIN = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIN);
    Object obj = (Object) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    return obj;
}
```

Dentro del main al hacer el try de la serialización he añadido un for para recorrer el objeto ya que he metido los datos dentro de un array y ha quedado de la siguiente forma:

```
try (/* VARIABLES */
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        Notas[] notas1dam = new Notas[6];
        double[] notasmedias = new double[6];
        int contador = 1;
        String nombre = "Dario";
        /* VARIABLES */

        System.out.println("Bienvenido al programa de tus notas. Introduce tus notas porfavor.");

        // INGRESAR LAS NOTAS DENTRO DEL ARRAY \ EL NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO LO HE DEFINIDO
        // ARRIBA PARA QUE NO ESTÉ PREGUNTANDO EL NOMBRE CADA VEZ Q METES LA NOTA
        for (int i = 0; i < notas1dam.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Introduce la nota de la " + contador + "º asignatura ");

            double notasalumno = sc.nextInt();
            notasmedias[i] = notasalumno;
            notas1dam[i] = new Notas(nombre, notasalumno);
            contador++;
        }

        // SERIALIZACION
        try {
            notasSerializacion.serialize(notas1dam, "hola.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        // SERIALIZACION

        // DESERIALIZACION
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < notas1dam.length; i++) {
                notas1dam = (Notas[]) notasSerializacion.deserialize("hola.txt");
                System.out.println(notas1dam[i]);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        // DESERIALIZACION Y A CONTINUACIÓN SACAMOS LA MEDIA
        System.out.println("La nota media del alumno '" + nombre + "' es: " + medianotas(notasmedias));
    }
}
```

Si alguien puede aportar otro tipo de solución se lo agradecería también así puedo darme cuenta de otras posibles soluciones.